# Invalid value "ssl_certificate" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've just uploaded an SSL certificate on a test server running Nginx. I've added the cert and key files paths into nginx.conf, but no matter what I try, I keep getting this error:

```
Feb 23 15:01:20 myserver systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Feb 23 15:01:21 myserver nginx[1315]: nginx: [emerg] invalid value "ssl_certificate" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:67
Feb 23 15:01:21 myserver nginx[1315]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Feb 23 15:01:21 myserver systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 23 15:01:21 myserver systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 23 15:01:21 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

I really, really don't get it: tried "/etc/pki/tls/certs/myserver.pem" or '/etc/pki/tls/certs/myserver.pem', doesn't change anything. I've triple-checked filenames, directories, I really have no clue.

Has anyone run into similar error message ? Didn't find much on Google or even here...

This is the juicy part of my nginx.conf file (line 67 is, of course the ssl_certificate one):

```
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  myserver;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/mymserver.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/myserver.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!DH;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config file

```
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
```

is missing the terminating `;`

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/managing-configuration-files/), it says,

> The configuration file consists of *directives* and their parameters. Simple (single‑line) directives each end with a semicolon. [....]

So, nginx reads this as a wrong syntax, and reports the wrong value.

Comment: My God I'm an idiot! Thank you very much, how did I miss it...